# Subplots and twinx axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, twinx

I was trying to make two subplots with twinx axis, 3 curves (curvey,curve1 and curve2) on the first subplot and 3 curves (curvey, curve3 and curve4) on the second subplot. But I'm not getting what I want. I wonder if you guys can help me please.

```
x = df['curvex']
y = df['curvey']
y1 = df['curve1']
y2 = df['curve2']
y3=df['curve3']
y4=df['curve4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,10), dpi=500)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
twin1 = ax.twinx()
twin2 = ax.twinx()

twin2.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.02))

p1, = ax.plot(x,y, 'bo--', label='curvey', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
p2, = twin1.plot(x,y1, 'go--', label='curvey1', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
p3, = twin2.plot(x,y2, 'ro--', label='curvey2', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
 
ax.set_xlabel('CURVEX')
ax.set_ylabel('CURVEY') 
twin1.set_ylabel('CURVE1')
twin2.set_ylabel('CURVE2')

ax.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
twin1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
twin2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=0.5, width=0.2)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
twin1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
twin2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)

ax.legend(handles=[p1,p2,p3])



plt.subplot(2,1,2)

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
twin3 = ax.twinx()
twin4 = ax.twinx()

twin4.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.02))

p1, = ax.plot(x,y, 'bo--', label='curvey', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
p4, = twin3.plot(x,y3, 'go--', label='curvey4', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
p5, = twin4.plot(x,y4, 'ro--', label='curvey5', markersize=0.1, linewidth=0.2)
 
ax.set_xlabel('CURVEX')
ax.set_ylabel('CURVEY') 
twin3.set_ylabel('CURVE4')
twin4.set_ylabel('CURVE5')

ax.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
twin3.yaxis.label.set_color(p4.get_color())
twin4.yaxis.label.set_color(p5.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=0.5, width=0.2)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
twin3.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p4.get_color(), **tkw)
twin4.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p5.get_color(), **tkw)

ax.legend(handles=[p1,p4,p5])

plt.show()
```

This is what I was getting. Y-axes on the left should be separated, for each subplot. Curvey, curve1 and curve2 should be on the first subplot, and curvey, curve3 and curve4 should be on the second subplot.In total, I want to see 3 curves in each subplot. I can't see legend neither. Y scales on the left and right are wrong also since the code is not good, I guess

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong when you didn't attach screenshot or data to plot it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to attach the image but it was too big. I will try to attach an screenshot as you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably lies in these lines:

> ```
> twin1 = ax.twinx()
> twin2 = ax.twinx()
> ```

Incorrectly, you make twins for the same axis.
Change the two subplot creation lines to this single line:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(40,10), dpi=500)
```

After that you can do:

```
twin1 = ax1.twinx()
twin2 = ax2.twinx()
```

Also, don't forget to plot and close the first figure before start working on the second figure:

```
ax.legend(handles=[p1,p2,p3])
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Hi czeni, first I want to thank you for try to help. Although there was a change in the result, it wasn't what I want. I'll attach screen of the desired plot I am looking for.

Comment: I have been trying to change a bit the code that you suggested and I think I've finally gotten what I want. Thanks man